# How to get value of a HTML tag receiving from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am receiving below html from vbscript page by ajax call.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" valign="top">
                    <div id="xyz"></div>
                    <input name="a1" type="hidden" value="">
                    <input name="a2" type="hidden" value="586546d5">
                    <input name="a3" type="hidden" value="13025">
                    <br clear="all">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to get value of input tag where `name="a2"` in ajax. i.e we want value `586546d5` in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert html string into jquery object and then get element in it:

```
$(returnehtml).find('[name=a2]').val();
```

Comment: Well I tried this one : var html = $.parseHTML(data);
  var result = $(html).find('[name=a2]').val();
  alert(result);  but it give undefined on alert box.

Comment: can you share the value of data??

Comment: Sorry, I can share it because it is valuable data but the format of HTML is almost same as describe above.

Answer (score 0):

use query selector

```
document.querySelector('input[name=a2]').value
```

Comment: yes spell mistake corrected. i think you could have edited it